# Bind multiple keys to a Table using template

Tags: javascript, data-binding, sapui5

I want to bind multiple keys from a JSON to a [sap.ui.table.Column](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.table.Column.html).
I am using a JSON-View. This is how it looks like:

```
{
  "Type": "sap.ui.core.mvc.JSONView",
  "content": [
    {
      "Type": "sap.ui.table.Table",
      "id": "backendConnectorsOverviewTable",
      "columns": [
        {
          "Type": "sap.ui.table.Column",
          "label": "Label",
          "template": {
            "Type": "sap.ui.commons.TextView",
            "text": "{text} {headerText}"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

And this is how my Data-JSON looks like:

```
{
  forms: [
    {
      text: "First Text"
    },
    {
      text: "Second Text"
    },
    {
      headerText: "Header Text"
    }
  ]
}
```

The Question is, is it possible to bind the Table-Column to multiple keys, like in my case **text and headerText**?
I had no success with multiple changes like:

```
"template": {
    "Type": "sap.ui.commons.TextView",
    "text": "{text} {headerText}"
  }

OR:

"template": {
    "Type": "sap.ui.commons.TextView",
    "text": "{/text} {/headerText}"
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible. Try this:

```
"template": {
    "Type": "sap.ui.commons.TextView",
    "text": "{ parts: [ { path: '/text' }, { path: '/headerText' } ] }"
}
```